# jquery trigger click event for 'a' tag

Tags: jquery, html, triggers, click

i am trying to trigger a click event for anchor tag inside 'li'. when click on 'li', i want to trigger a tag inside that 'li'. my html and jQuery given below. below jquery showing this error.

"too much recursion .."

```
<li><a href="link">link text</a></li>


$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#menu-top li").click(function(){
  $(this).children('a').click();
 });
});
```

please help me. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `trigger` event!

```
<li><a href="link">link text</a></li>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#menu-top li").click(function(){
  $(this).children('a').trigger('click');
 });
});
```

> Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods
>   are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired
>   manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger()
>   executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event
>   were triggered naturally by the user

[jQuery Trigger Event](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'find' instead of 'children'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#menu-top li").click(function(){
  $(this).find('a').click();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call event.stopPropagation() to call click recursively as clicking the a will trigger the click for its parent li. This will again cause the click of anchor tag which results in recursive call.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/mzpbLw48/5/)**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#menu-top li").click(function (event) {
          alert("li clicked");
          $(this).children('a').click();       
      });
      $("#menu-top li a").click(function (event) {
          //your code
          alert("a clicked");
          event.stopPropagation();         
      });
  });
```

Comment: i have applied this changes. now error not showing. but trigger not working!

Comment: Check the live demo, if this is what you are trying for?

Comment: same thing happens on my code. two alerts shong in my code too. but click not going to link location. i added a link(http://google.com) on ur demo href. but that not working

Comment: Check my updated answer, we do not need event.preventDefault. I forgot to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code:

```
$("#menu-top li a").click(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will prevent the click event to propagate from child element a to parent element li.